# Running postgresql function for each row in other select returning the combined result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to run the following query on my database:

```
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS relation,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS total_size_pretty, pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) AS total_size
FROM pg_class C
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
  AND C.relkind <> 'i'
  AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
```

Then for each row in the result run:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(dead_tuple_len + free_space) AS recoverable_space_pretty, (dead_tuple_len + free_space) AS recoverable_space FROM extensions.pgstattuple(relation);
```

How can I do that in Postgresql returning a result combining the two so I for each row get: `relation, total_size_pretty, total_size, recoverable_space_pretty, recoverable_space`?

BONUS: I would also like to output the result as CSV

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the relation between these two queries? I mean, how the columns connect with each other. A simple `CTE` with a `COPY` statement should suffice. I can post a generic solution

Comment: The second query uses `relation` from each row in first query within the `FROM extensions.pgstattuple(relation)`. So in other words, for each row I will query two more columns based on `relation`

Comment: Can you check if this here works for you? Since I don't have all your tables I cannot check myself :) `COPY (
WITH j AS (
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS relation,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS total_size_pretty, pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) AS total_size
FROM pg_class C
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
  AND C.relkind <> 'i'
  AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast')
SELECT extensions.pgstattuple(j.relation) FROM j
) TO STDOUT CSV HEADER;` Hopefully something we can work on :D

Comment: This is the logic I thought about: `COPY (
WITH j AS (
SELECT 1 AS q1
)
SELECT j.q1+1 AS q2 FROM j) TO STDOUT CSV HEADER;`

Comment: Hmm looks like it isn't working since some of the internal queries of the functions relies on views: `ERROR:  "pg_buffercache" (view) is not supported`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-with.html) and [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-copy.html) should do:

```
COPY (
WITH j AS (
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS relation,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS total_size_pretty, pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) AS total_size
FROM pg_class C
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
  AND C.relkind <> 'i'
  AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
)
SELECT pg_size_pretty((pgstattuple(j.relation)).dead_tuple_len + (pgstattuple(j.relation)).free_space) AS recoverable_space_pretty, (
                      (pgstattuple(j.relation)).dead_tuple_len + (pgstattuple(j.relation)).free_space) AS recoverable_space 
FROM j
) TO STDOUT CSV HEADER;
```

query returned copy data:

```
recoverable_space_pretty,recoverable_space
8104 bytes,8104
7508 bytes,7508
7992 bytes,7992
8044 bytes,8044
0 bytes,0
5068 bytes,5068
0 bytes,0
0 bytes,0
8104 bytes,8104
7724 bytes,7724
0 bytes,0
0 bytes,0
0 bytes,0
```

**Note:** In case you can afford writing on the database server file system, change the `STDOUT` to a path of your choice.

Comment: Thanks! Works well